# Count the objects inside of an array on each document MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

My documents are organized this way:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ea899d7e7da54cabbc022e7"),
        "date" : ISODate("2018-01-27T00:00:00Z"),
        "vehicleid" : 32028,
        "points" : [
                {
                        "direction" : 225,
                        "location" : {
                                "type" : "Point",
                                "coordinates" : [
                                        -3.801898,
                                        -38.501078
                                ]
                        },
                        "odometer" : 134746396,
                        "routecode" : 0,
                        "speed" : 0,
                        "deviceid" : 148590,
                        "metrictimestamp" : ISODate("2018-01-27T23:32:03Z")
                }
```

Where points is an array of objects. I need to group this documents and return the amount of elements inside each array. I guess that is something like:

```
pipe = [ 
  {
    '$project':{
      "_id":0
    }
  },
  {
    '$group':{
      "_id":{
        "vehicleid":"$vehicleid",
        "date":"$date"
      },'count':{'$size':'points'}
    }
  }
         ]
```

**Detail: I need to run this on pymongo.**

Comment: `{ '$size': 'points' }` should be `{ '$size': '$points' }`

Comment: pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: unknown group operator '$size', returns this error

Comment: It should be  `{ 'count': { '$sum': { '$size': '$points' } } }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `$sum` to sum the size of each array like this

```js
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "vehicleid": "$vehicleid",
        "date": "$date"
      },
      "count": { "$sum": { "$size": "$points" } }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the following aggregation pipelines. You will get the size of the `points` array field. Each pipeline uses different approach, and the output details differ, but the size info will be same.

The code runs with PyMongo:

```
pipeline = [
    { 
        "$unwind": "$points" 
    },
    { 
        "$group": { 
            "_id": { "vehicleid": "$vehicleid", "date": "$date" }, 
            "count": { "$sum": 1 } 
        }
    }
]

pipeline = [
  { 
      "$addFields": { "count": { "$size": "$points" } }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can follow this code**

```
$group : {
       _id : {
        "vehicleid":"$vehicleid",
        "date":"$date"
         count: { $sum: 1 }
       }
    }
```